# How to interpret gdb disassemble output?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to match the gdb disassemble output (**disas [address]**)  against the source code. I know that such mapping can be done using **(gdb) info line *address** to find the matching line. However I do not quite understand the format of the output of disassemble. Specifically, what do the following numbers, +4722, and +4281, mean ?

```
0x00002ad61e45bd02 <+4722>:  jmpq   0x2ad61e45bb49     <MsgManager::ForwardMsg(boost::shared_ptr<Channel>, boost::shared_ptr<Msg>, boost::shared_ptr<Context>)+4281>
```

I am using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Specifically, what do the following numbers, +4722, and +4281, mean

The instruction at address `0x00002ad61e45bd02`, which is 4722 bytes from the start of current function (most likely `MsgManager::ForwardMsg()`) is a jump to address `0x2ad61e45bb49`, which is 4281 bytes from the start of `MsgManager::ForwardMsg()`.

You may also find `(gdb) disas/m` command handy.

Comment: I think you might show up a little bit more effort in your research, you might for example start reading a little bit of GDB's actual documentation on disassembly https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html#Machine-Code and also searching for the asm reference on  your specific architecture